# Prove $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f'(x)= c \implies \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}\to c$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Suppose $f\in C^1(\Bbb R), f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f'(x)= c$ for some constant $c$.

How could we show $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to c$ as $x\to \infty$ also? L'Hopital's rule seems to give this, but obviously cannot be applied as we don't know whether $f(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.

Also for my own curiosity, does the (presumably correct) forwards implication apply backwards?
As in, does $\frac{f(x)}{x}\to c \Rightarrow f'(x)\to c$ as $x\to \infty$ also?

Comment: If $f'(x) \to c$ as $x \to \infty,$ then on $[N, \infty)$ (for some $N$) we have $f'(x) \geq c/2$ and then, $f(x) - f(N) \geq c/2(x - N).$ So $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty.$

Comment: @WillM. : That argument doesn't seem to work for any constant $f$, all of which have $f' \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @EricTowers It was $c$ and I should assume $c > 0.$

Comment: Although, if $c < 0,$ the same proof-idea shows $f(x) \to -\infty$ and L'Hôpital's rule still applies. The case $c = 0$ needs more thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'Hopital's rule can be used, since it is enough that the denominator goes to $\infty$.

The converse implication is not true, as you can see considering
$$
f(x) = cx + \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}\,.
$$